# Remove Price Filter on certain categories

Tags: category, price, layered-navigation, filter

How can you remove the Price filter on certain categories?

The price filter doesn't always apply, so I need a way to remove it under certain conditions, such as the category name.

I've looked at the `catalog_controller_category_init_after` event, which I can then create an if statement for when the category name matches. But I've been unable to find a way to actually remove the price filter.

Answer (score 1):

Magento, do not have this type event by  which you  remove  Price attribute from Filter on certain categories.

**Here are need some little hack code for this case at**

```
app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTEMPLATE>template>catalog/layer/view.phtml

  <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()):?>
  <?php $show=1;?>
    <!-- curern filter price and currentc Cat match -->
  <?php if($_filter->getFilter()->getRequestVar()!=='price'){?>
    <?php if(Mage::registry('current_category') &&(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()==$catId)):
    $show=0;
        endif;
     ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <!-- check show 
  <?php if($show==1){?>
  <?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php endif;?>
```